# configure right click mouse for code comments in phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to configure comments code directly when right click mouse? For example, I select some code, then right click, then I can choose html comment, php comment, multiline comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. But you can add your feature request on JetBrains tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all menus in PhpStorm are fully customisable.

Open `Settings|Menus and Toolbars`, then expand `Editor popup menu`, select any suitable existing element and use `Add After` to add one of `Main Menu|Code|Comment ...` actions.

This will make them appear in "right click menu" within editors. Action may be disabled depending on whether it is defined for the language at caret position.

Note, that built-in actions will automatically choose comment style depending on context.
If your intent is to specifically surround the selection with i.e. *html* comment you'll need to take additional steps - create a custom template for `Surround with` action, recording a `Macro` that invokes it on selection and adding that macro to the menu as described above.